# How to get all variables available in scope?

Tags: python

If I have the following code:

```
var_global = "global"
def outer() :
    var_outer = "outer"
    def inner() :
        var_inner = "inner"
        # How to get here all variables available (it should contain
        # var_inner, var_outer, var_global)?
        print("inner", locals(), globals())
    return inner
```

And I run:

```
outer()()
```

I would like to get all variables at `print` location. This should include `var_outer` as well. But neither `locals` nor `globals` provide it.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem; why do you need to know all the variables in scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var_outer` truly ISN'T available in `inner()`.  Making a variable available in a nested function requires that the variable be stored in a different way from the start; Python did not do so, due to lack of any reference to the variable from a nested function.  If you did insert such a reference (such as the bare statement `var_outer`), it would show up in the output of `locals()`.

Answer (score 6):

The closure variable mechanisms that would provide `inner` with access to `var_outer` are only triggered if `inner` actually contains accesses to the `var_outer` variable. Otherwise, `var_outer` is not saved, and no introspection will give you access to it.

Answer (score 0):

var_outer can access var_inner by nonlocal.

```
var_global = "global"
def outer():
    var_outer = "outer"
    def inner():
        var_inner = "inner"
        print("inner", locals(), globals())
        nonlocal var_outer
        print(var_outer)
    return inner

outer()()
```

Will print:

```
inner {'var_outer': 'outer', 'var_inner': 'inner'} [...]
```